# disable UINavigationBar gradient

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

Does anybody know how to disable gradient in UINavigationBar and make it totally black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that descends from UINavigationBar and implements its own `drawRect:` method. You may have to draw the title and buttons yourself (in which case, why not just use a custom view?)